# Helping for eigenvalue and eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I am lost in relation to a way to solve these eigenvalues and eigenvector questions. Please, someone could guide me on how can I take a solution? I will appreciate your help.

- Let A be a real n x n matrix such that A^T = A. Show that if all n eigenvalues λj, j=1,..., n are distinct (λi different of λj for j different i), then the eigenvectors are mutually orthogonaç so that Vi^T.Vj =0 if i different of j.
- Let A be a symmetric positive definite nxn matrix and define the Rayleigh quotient for any x different of 0 by

  ```
                           R(x)=(x^T.Ax)/(x^T.x)
  ```

Let λ be an eigenvalue of A with corresponding eigenvalue v. Show that

```
                                 ∇R(v)=0,
```

and that
λ=R(v)

i.e. the eigenvectors are the stationary points of the Rayleigh quotient and the eigenvalues are the local maxima, minima or saddle points. Hint: note that

```
                     ∇R(x) = 2(1/x^T x)Ax - 2(x^T Ax/x^T x)x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $AX=aX$, take transoose and use $A^T=A$ then
$$A X_1=a_1 X_1 \implies X^T_1 A=a_1 X^T_1~~~~(1)$$
and
$$A X_2=a_2 X_1 \implies X^T_2 A=a_2 X^T_2~~~~(2)$$
Multiply (1) by $X_2$ from right on both sides, we get
$$X_1^T A X_2=a_1 X_1^T X_2~~~~(3)$$
Next, multiply (2) by $X_1$ and take transpose to gry
$$X_2^T A X_1=a_2 X_2^T \implies X_1^T A X_2=a_2 X_1^T X_2~~~~(4)$$
Subtract (4) from (3) to get
$$(a_1-a_2)X_1^TX_2=0$$
This implies that if $a_1 \ne a_2$, then $X_!^TX_2=0$, implyimg that eigenvectors $X_1, X_2$ are orthogonal.